# SharePoint Site redirect based on SharePoint Group

Tags: redirect, sharepoint

I have three separate user group say HR, IT and Supplies this three groups have their own sub sites.
HR=/site1
IT=/site2
Supplies=/site3
but they have a common top level site say "http://xyz.com"

When a user from HR opens the top level site he should be redirected automatically to the respective sub-site (site1) similarly IT to site2 and same with Supplies.

Can this be done using OOTB method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is using unique permissions at subsite level, following might work. I am explaining it for a single group IT:
[1] Add content editors in your welcome page of root lelvel site.
[2] Set chrome type to none, and set all it sharepoint groups in audience 
[3] set content to

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='/IT/';</script>
```

Same way add content editor web part for each subsite.

This way, if someone from IT group logs in, then and then the content editor web part become visible and the script redirects them  to IT home page. This is just a hint, not a real solution.

Draw backs:
[1] Admins will also redirect to the same page and no one will be able to edit the page.
[2] Someone having permission to access more than one department will redirect to any site randomly based on script execution order.

There are ways to improve script written in content editor web part to overcome both of the above changes. You can simply using sharepoint javascript api to improve the script.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, i have already tried the above solution but i cant use this one because of the draw backs of edit mode what if in case i have to change the existing IT Department URL or do some edits to the webpart.Do we have a way to edit the CEWP for Admins atleast.

Comment: move the script to a separate file in asset or style library and set the link in content editor web part

Comment: Thats a point also but if i want to edit the webpart itself the CEWP properties, i am not worried about the top level site because it is just used for redirect, anyways for the worst case i would be having an admin account to do edits that's not part of any audience group of webpart so that is wont be redirected.